# Python KeyError when using .pivot_table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use Python's .pivot_table to pivot a CSV. I have imported the correct modules:

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

I have read in my csv file:

```
training_tracker = pd.read_csv('Training Tracker_v02.csv')
```

And I have implemented .pivot_table:

```
pivot_test = training_tracker.pivot_table(index=['POD', 'Name', 'Date 
Start', 'Date Finish', 'Total Days', 'Training Status', 'Exam Needed'],
                                         columns='Training', values='DemoA')
```

However when I run my program I get the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/training tracker/app1.py", line 33, in <module>
    columns='Training', values='DemoA')
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\training tracker\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4468, in pivot_table
    margins_name=margins_name)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\training tracker\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 58, in pivot_table
    raise KeyError(i)
KeyError: 'DemoA'
```

My file imports fine as I can import and read from it. What I'm trying to do is pivot the column 'Training' and break its contents into separate columns. I have marked the columns that I do not with to pivot in the index.

Any help would be very grateful.

Update: Here is an image of the data file
[image: Data File]

Thanks,
Tony.

Comment: Can you post sample data from your dataset with headers

Comment: Please show the output of `training_tracker.columns`.

Comment: The output from `training_tracker.columns` is `Index(['POD', 'Name', 'Training', 'Date Start', 'Date Finish', 'Total Days',
       'Training Status', 'Exam Needed', 'Exam Date', 'Exam Day Needed',
       'Certificate Gained'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: Here is a sample of the data file: Dept Name Training Date Start Date Finish totaldays Training Status Exam Needed
Dept 1 John Training1 31/01/2018 01/02/2018 2 Complete No
Dept 2 John Training2 31/01/2018 01/02/2018 2 Complete No
Dept 3 Frank Training3 01/02/2018 02/02/2018 2 Complete No

Comment: @TonyStaunton Problem is in `values='DemoA` argument, to `pivot_table` method. According to data, that you presented, your DataFrame doesn't have column named `DemoA`. Is this column present in `'Training Tracker_v02.csv'` file, and not making it in DataFrame?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin That worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.